# Infinite Scrolling in Iron Router based on Discover Meteor

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I can't seem to get the infinite scrolling to work from Commit 12-5. It says just to `mrt add iron-router-progress` and everything should work, but my page keeps refreshing. Here's what I'm working with:

```
PostsListController = RouteController.extend({
    template: 'blog',
    increment: 20,
    limit: function() {
        return parseInt(this.params.postsLimit) || this.increment;
    },
    waitOn: function() {
        return Meteor.subscribe('posts', this.limit());
    },
    posts: function() {
        return Posts.find({}, {
            limit: this.limit()
        });
    },
    data: function() {
        var hasMore = this.posts().count() === this.limit();
        var nextPath = this.route.path({
            postsLimit: this.limit() + this.increment
        });
        return {
            posts: this.posts(),
            nextPath: hasMore ? nextPath : null
        };
    }
});

Router.map(function() {
    this.route('blog', {
        path: '/:postsLimit?',
        controller: PostsListController
    })
})

Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout',
    notFoundTemplate: 'notFound',
});
```

Everything seems to work EXCEPT when I click load more, the page blinks and jumps back up to the top!

Comment: On the first look your code seems fine. Did you also made your click-more button reactive based on the counter? So does you route changes when you click on the button? Maybe an additionally hint, the load-more logic is independent of the iron-router-progress package. The iron-router-progress-package just shows a small progressbar on top of your site. Like the red one on youtube.

Comment: I'm just using the `<a class="load-more" href="{{nextPath}}">load more </a>` that was specified in the book... Makes sense that it is just a progress bar, haha. Maybe its something with Blaze?

Answer (score 1):

As you can read in the GitHub issues related the commit, it is actually a bug in the 0.7.1 version of iron-router. With the version they used (look up the smart.lock file) it won't refresh and go to the top.