# How to stop MeteorJs to scroll to top of page when template re rendered

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

The question says it all. I am using infinite scroll example from Meteropedia http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/Infinite_Scrolling but when I scroll down to load more documents from collection to page move to top. I have tried this solution [How to prevent content from scrolling when Meteor updates the collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768957/how-to-prevent-content-from-scrolling-when-meteor-updates-the-collection) but still facing the same problem. Pleas help me resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you are using iron router and it is unfortunately due to an unresolved bug that gathered some attention due to its manifestation on the Discover Meteor book.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23902891/infinite-scrolling-in-iron-router-based-on-discover-meteor) in fact asks the same while, more info can be found on the discover meteor book's [github issues](https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/Microscope/issues/106) with [further discussion here](https://github.com/Multiply/iron-router-progress/issues/22#issuecomment-47304035)

Basically, you need to revert back to meteor 0.8.2 and iron router 0.7.0